# Equal horizontal alignment of three divs

Tags: html, css

I want to create three `div` boxes (black, red and blue), which are evenly spaced horizontally. In my attempt, I set each `div` to `inline-block`, and then set the three `divs` to `left`, `center` and `right` align. However, when rendered, the three boxes are all aligned to the left. What I actually want is for the first box to be up against the left of the outer div, the third box to the up against the right of the outer div, and then the middle box to be exactly in the middle of the first and third boxes.

Here's my code:

```html
<div style="width:1000px">

    <div style="display:inline-block; text-align:left; width:200px; height:100px; background-color:black"></div>
    
    <div style="display:inline-block; text-align:center; width:200px; height:100px; background-color:red"></div>
    
    <div style="display:inline-block; text-align:right; width:200px; height:100px; background-color:blue"></div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Yes I just added that, the outer div is 1000px in width, so it should fit all three in a row.

Comment: What excatly are you trying to achive here? It's not clear

Comment: By pushed to the left, I mean that the divs are all aligned to the left of the outer div. What I actually want is the first box on the right, the second box in the middle, and then the third box up against the right of the outer div.

Comment: `text-align` aligns the text **in** the boxes, not the boxes themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a dozen different ways to do this. Here's one:

```html
<div style="width:1000px; text-align:center">
  <div style="display:inline-block; float:left; width:200px; height:100px; background-color:black"></div>
  <div style="display:inline-block; width:200px; height:100px; background-color:red"></div>
  <div style="display:inline-block;  float:right;width:200px; height:100px; background-color:blue"></div>
</div>
```

Float the first and last div and set the text align on the parent to center to handle the middle div.

OK, here's another (with flexbox):

```html
<div style="width:1000px; display:flex; justify-content: space-between;">
  <div style="width:200px; height:100px; background-color:black"></div>
  <div style="width:200px; height:100px; background-color:red"></div>
  <div style="width:200px; height:100px; background-color:blue"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: display:inline-block; and float:left; is not a good combination. Floating elements have naturally display: block;

Comment: @JohannKratzik Try removing the inline block from that first example and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can float each one of the divs to the left inside a 100% width container, then go for 33% width on each.

```css
#cointainer {
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
#left {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
    background-color: black;
}
#center {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}
#right {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="cointainer">
    <div id="left">blah blah blah</div>
    <div id="center">blah blah blah</div>
    <div id="right">blah blah blah</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox:

```
<div style="width:1000px; display: flex; justify-content: space-between">
    <div style="width:200px; height:100px; background-color:black"></div>  
    <div style="width:200px; height:100px; background-color:red"></div>    
    <div style="width:200px; height:100px; background-color:blue">
```

[Complete tutorial here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)